# entity framework concurrency: transactions or concurrency fixed?

Tags: entity-framework, concurrency, transactions

I need to make stock control, so I need to ensure that when I modified the amount of product, is doing in the right way. I am using Entity framework 4.0

For example, if I use a transaction, when I load the record from the database, the recored is blocked, so I can substract or add to the loaded amount, the number of items that I need. However, this block the record in the database and perhaps for performance reasons is not the best way. This makes me ask when to use transactions with EF.

The other option is to use the concurrency fixed of entity framework, using a timespan column to detect if the record has been changed. In this case, if the record has been modified between my load and my update, I get the exception of concurrency. But it could occur that in my exception handler, if I update my context with the database data, between my refresh and the savechanges could be changed again.

Other problem is I finally can save the changes. For example, I have 10 units, I need to substract 8 but between my load and my update, other person substract 5 units. If I subtract 8, then in stock I have -3 units. This is not possible. If I have a transaction, I load the record, is blocked, so I can check if I have enough units, if yes, I can subtrack, if not, I send an exception.

So my question is, I know that EF is a transaction by itself, but it exists also transactions in EF, so it would be useful in some cases. When to use EF and cocurrency fixed and when to use transactions?

Thanks.
Daimroc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transactions should not be used to solve concurrency. You should make transactions as short as possible to not block your databases. The way to go here is optimistic concurrency - in the database (SqlServer) you create a rowversion column that changes automatically each time a row is modified. You use it as concurrency token. When saving changes EF checks this against the value on the entity and if they don't match it throws an exception.
Note that for SaveChanges EF always creates a transaction since typically you save more than one entity and if something goes wrong the database needs to be reverted to the original state - otherwise it would be in a corrupt state. 
To prevent from going below zero - if you use the optimistic concurrency - you won't be able to save if the value in the database changed since the concurrency token will be different because row was modified and therefore the check on the client should be sufficient. Alternatively you could map saving an entity to a stored procedure that will check the value before saving and would return an error if the value after saving would be incorrect.